# How to dynamically delete jpg files or all files from a SharePoint Folder

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to figure out how to delete only the jpg files from a SharePoint folder (SP 2013).  I am able to delete a specific .jpg file but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to delete all the jpg files.

Also I would know how to delete every file within the folder as well.  I am in need of both method.  I included my code with my most recent attempt to delete only the jpg files.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$.ajax({ 
 type: "POST", 
 url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/dcsa/ep/epMainFiles/photoGallery/photoGalleryTest/*.jpg)/recycle()",
 
 headers: { 
     "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", 
     "IF-MATCH": "*", 
     "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() 
 }, 

 success: function(data){ 
     alert("Document is recycled!"); 
 }, 
 error: function(error){ 
     alert("Error"); console.log(error); 
 } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this rest API to delete the folder.

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
If-Match: "{etag or *}"
X-HTTP-Method: "DELETE"
X-RequestDigest: "{form_digest_value}"
```

---

You could use the filter keyword to get all jpg file id, then delete them one by one.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('doc2')/Items?$select=ID,FileLeafRef&$filter=substringof('.jpg',FileLeafRef)
```

Delete list item rest endpoint:

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items({item_id})
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
Content-Type: "application/json"
If-Match: "{etag or *}"
X-HTTP-Method: "DELETE"
```

Comment: The method to delete is folder is really good and can be my plan B.  But is it possible to delete the all the content within the folder and not just the folder.  The folder contain .jpg file of photos that displays on a HTML.  These image will display on the page for a certain number of days then remove (deleted from the folder).  We like to add new photos for future display.  Adding a new folder each time may cause issues with the users.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files` to get all images under the folder.Then compare the image suffix in the return value, and delete the matching endpoint with this endpointPOST `https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/{file_name}')`